# can't plot in R studio on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, plot, rstudio, homebrew, ubuntu-16.04

HI I installed R with brew install R and then R studio from the deb file.

When I enter R through ubuntu (16.04) terminal and type plot(cars) I get a popup with a plot.

When I enter R through r studio and type plot(cars) I get an error.

By the way I have zlib and gtk+ installed via brew so I'm not sure what's going on.

Your guys help would sure be appreciated.

> plot(cars)
>   Error in RStudioGD() : 
>     Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (R code execution error)
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In grDevices:::png("/tmp/Rtmpsjmflh/c9345ef70b9a4dc9a1f9f5579bfaada6.png",  :
>     unable to load shared object '/home/tha/.linuxbrew/Cellar/r/3.4.3_2/lib/R/modules//R_X11.so':
>     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /home/tha/.linuxbrew/lib/libpng16.so.16)

Answer (score 2):

> HI I installed R with brew install R

That is not the best idea given that you are on Ubuntu. We have properly maintained *and current* R binaries for you [here at CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/).  When you use that, 'it all just works'.

Even if you don't use the CRAN apt repo, using the R version *that is part of your Ubuntu release* will work, albeit possibly an older version.

Comment: thanks but R works fine it is just rstudio is not accessing some program or library it needs to popup plots on the screen.

Comment: RStudio is self-contained; ie its plot device code does not rely on R. Your mixing of two package systems likely confused, and the fact that R on the command-line works has nothing to do with the trouble you created for RStudio.  Again, I think this is due to how you chose to install programs.